# SQL output: Is it possible to create a temporary output column?

Tags: sql

For example, I have a table as below in my database:

| Item ID | Item Name | Price | Item Status |

where Item ID = int, Item Name = string, Price = int, **Item Status = Enum**

where as for Item status...
Let's say "2" represents "Coming Soon",

"1" represents "Available",

while "0" represents "Sold Out"

I want to show the information such that I can tell the user who views the output table knows the status in a more acceptable output (string) rather than looking at the Enum values:

```
| Item ID | Item Name | Price         | Item Status | **Description** |
| 123     | Apple     | [some number] | 0           |   Sold Out      |
| 234     | Orange    | [some number] | 2           |   Coming Soon   |
```

where the **Description** is the **temporary** column I would like to display as an additional information.

May I know how the syntax goes in one GO?

Please guide me. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well the easiest way to do this would be to use a CASE statement - providing that you do only have 3 descriptions?

```
select ItemId,
       Item_name,
       price,
       Item_status,
       Case
       When Item_status = 0 then 'Sold Out'
       When Item_status = 1 then 'Available'
       When Item_status = 2 then 'Coming Soon'
       End as [Description]

From dbo.YourTable
```

Another option if to create a temporary table and join on to that.

```
Create Table #TempEnums
(
Id int,
Desc varchar(50)
)
Insert Into #TempEnums
Select 0, 'Sold Out' Union Select 1, 'Available' Union Select 2, 'Coming Soon'
```

Then simply join on to the temp table

```
select a.ItemId,
       a.Item_name,
       a.price,
       a.Item_status,
       b.Desc as [Description]

From dbo.YourTable a
Join #TempEnums b on a.Item_Status = b.Id
```

**EDIT**

To change the datatype of the `[description]` column just wrap in a `Convert` statement

```
       Convert(Varchar(25),  
       Case
       When Item_status = 0 then 'Sold Out'
       When Item_status = 1 then 'Available'
       When Item_status = 2 then 'Coming Soon'
       End) as [Description]
```

Comment: Will it still show the output as string, since the data type of my Item_status is enum?

Comment: Enum is just an integer in SQL, so yes the output will be a string

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I chose your first option.
Is it also possible to declare the [Description]'s data type manually by myself after the END AS [Description]?

Comment: @Melissa: Yes, just wrap the `case` statement in a `convert` statement. I've updated my answer for you with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table **descr** (id,string) in which you put these records:
(0, 'Sold Out'), (1, 'Available'), (2, 'Coming Soon')
and then join tables during output...

```
SELECT table.*,descr.description FROM table INNER JOIN descr
ON table.enum_col = descr.id
```

Or you could use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) command...

**EDITED:**
I prefer the first solution, because if in future you have to add another enum value, you can do it just working on db; using *case* you should change your query that could be hard-written (and compiled) in your software and so you have to recompile... and sometimes it's a problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree :)
The first option fits my case.
Thank you for your reply. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Melissa: glad to help you. Just one thing, I tell you because I see you're new here: accept some answer if you think is the one for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

There would appear to be a good case for a lookup base table (i.e. 'permanent'). But you can materize one 'on the fly' using a CTE e.g.

```
WITH StatusesLookup (status_ID, status_description)
     AS
     (
      SELECT status_ID, CAST(status_description AS VARCHAR(20))
        FROM (
              VALUES (0, 'Sold Out'), 
                     (1, 'Available'), 
                     (2, 'Coming Soon')
             ) AS StatusesLookup (status_ID, status_description)
     )
SELECT T1.Item_ID, T1.Item_Name, T1.Price, 
       T1.Item_Status, S1.status_description AS Description
  FROM YourTable AS T1
       INNER JOIN StatusesLookup AS S1
          ON S1.status_ID = T1.Item_Status;
```

Answer (score 0):

With Macro's table called ItemStatus (0, 'Sold Out'), (1, 'Available'), (2, 'Coming Soon'), the select would be:

```
select a.ItemId,
       a.Item_name,
       a.price,
       a.ItemStatus,
       b.Description
From ItemTable a JOIN ItemStatus b
          ON a.ItemStatusId = b.ItemStatusId
```

Answer (score 0):

No doubt CASE Statement is a good way to do this, use a User defined function instead of putting CASE statement in the SELECT statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_Set_Status 
(
    @ID INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(25)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(25)

    SELECT @Result =   Case
                       When @ID = 0 then 'Sold Out'
                       When @ID = 1 then 'Available'
                       When @ID = 2 then 'Coming Soon'
                       End
    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

Eg:

```
SELECT ItemId,
       Item_name,
       price,
       Item_status,
       DBO.udf_Set_Status (Item_status) AS [Item_status],
FROM dbo.YourTable
```