# SQL Query Inner Join with Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, common-table-expression

I'm trying to set values in a temp table using the examples shown here: [SQL output: Is it possible to create a temporary output column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961810/sql-output-is-it-possible-to-create-a-temporary-output-column)

I have created my initial table, where I'm using the column names to base the population of a new column of values "operdesc".

Here is my working table query where I get the COLUMN_NAME value I need. I want to add a temp column "OPERAND":

```
SELECT     COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, 'OPERAND' AS TempField, 
                  CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'Street' THEN '=' WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'Town' THEN 'CW' END AS OPERAND FROM         INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE    (TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo') AND (TABLE_NAME = 'Customers') ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
```

However, I want to take it a step further and simplify it using a temp join. I followed this example: [SQL output: Is it possible to create a temporary output column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961810/sql-output-is-it-possible-to-create-a-temporary-output-column) but am hung up on my script. This is what I have but it's not working, hopefully I'm close:

```
WITH XOperLU (xopername, xoperdesc)
 AS
 (
  SELECT xopername, CAST(xoperdesc AS VARCHAR(20))
    FROM (
          VALUES ('Street', 'SS'), 
                 ('Town', 'TW')                    
         ) AS XOperLU (xopername, xoperdesc)
 ) SELECT COLUMN_NAME as T1.COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE as T1.DATA_TYPE, S1.xoperdesc AS Description FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  AS T1 WHERE    (TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo') AND (TABLE_NAME = 'Clients') 
   INNER JOIN XOperLU AS S1
      ON S1.xopername = T1.COLUMN_NAME;
```

The 'Clients' table is a view.

Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it almost ok but you had `T1` alias used in column alias instead of column and most importantly you had `WHERE` before `JOIN`. This works:

```
WITH XOperLU (xopername, xoperdesc)
 AS
 (
  SELECT xopername, CAST(xoperdesc AS VARCHAR(20))
    FROM (
          VALUES ('Street', 'SS'), 
                 ('Town', 'TW')                    
         ) AS XOperLU (xopername, xoperdesc)
 ) SELECT T1.COLUMN_NAME as COLUMN_NAME, T1.DATA_TYPE as DATA_TYPE, S1.xoperdesc AS Description FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  AS T1 
   INNER JOIN XOperLU AS S1
      ON S1.xopername = T1.COLUMN_NAME
      WHERE    (TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo') AND (TABLE_NAME = 'Clients')
```

If you want to see all other columns that don't have specified description to be set to something, e.g. 'XX', you can use left join:

```
WITH XOperLU (xopername, xoperdesc)
 AS
 (
  SELECT xopername, CAST(xoperdesc AS VARCHAR(20))
    FROM (
          VALUES ('Street', 'SS'), 
                 ('Town', 'TW')                    
         ) AS XOperLU (xopername, xoperdesc)
 ) SELECT T1.COLUMN_NAME as COLUMN_NAME, T1.DATA_TYPE as DATA_TYPE, ISNULL(S1.xoperdesc,'XX') AS Description FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  AS T1 
   LEFT JOIN XOperLU AS S1
      ON S1.xopername = T1.COLUMN_NAME
      WHERE    (TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo') AND (TABLE_NAME = 'Clients')
```

Comment: Thanks! Second set of eyes worked perfectly. The only tweak needed now is so I see all the records in the original COLUMN_NAME and set the rest of the records in 'Description' as defined (as I have 'Street', 'SS'). This would create NULL values for them in 'Description'. I'd want to define a default value 'XX' so it doesn't say null. Make any sense? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to tweak it so I see all the records(COLUMN_NAMES) with Description set to 'XX' for the ones I don't set values for?

Comment: Excellente! Thanks so much, worked great. I was missing the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I'd love to have an increment ID field. where would I add a SELECT INTO statement in the above? Thanks in advance.